# Error installing Nativescript on Mac M2 Sonoma 14.4.1

Tags: macos, nativescript, node-gyp

I'm trying to install Nativescript on my new Mac and I'm having some problems with it.
I've followed the installation steps on [NativeScript's installation guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/setup/macos#installing-node) for both, Android and iOS, but on both it fails on the final step with is actually installing Nativescript, but I'm always getting the same error.
I've been trying to find some way to fix it on Google but I'm not having any luck, so I thought I could ask here.

Nativescript install command:

```
npm install -g nativescript
```

Error Dump on the Terminal:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@21.7.1 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.2 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/bin/python3.12"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/bin/python3.12
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/node-gyp/21.7.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/node-gyp/21.7.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/node-gyp/21.7.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents) while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:297:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/21.7.1/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v21.7.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```